# Close login modal after register modal

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Is there a way within Ionic to close a specific modal? Right now my flow is that I open a login modal and then the user can create an account which opens another modal. Upon successful signup, they get logged in and both modals should close but I'm only able to get the register closed.

```
this.closeModal();      
this.viewCtrl.dismiss('LoginPage');
```

The second line does nothing. How would I dismiss the second modal after the first one closes? Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Can you show more `code` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution to my problem was to just close one modal before opening another one.

Comment: But if the user first opens the SignInPage -> SingUpPage, and then closes that last page without creating a new account, shouldn't the SignInPage be shown?

Comment: @sebaferreras It will be shown because the only other option to close the register page is to use a specific button that will open the login.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a value success from the registration page. And on the login page access the value. If it is success then this.viewCtrl.dismiss().
Yiu have to dismiss the view in both pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could return a result from the `SignUpPage` (true if the user was able to signup successfully), and check it in the `SignInPage`, to see if that modal should also be closed. It'd look like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'page-sign-in',
    templateUrl: 'sign-in.html'
})
export class SignInPage {

    constructor(private viewCtrl: ViewController, private modalCtrl: ModalController) {}

    // ...

    // Method that redirects the user to the SignUpPage
    public openSignUp(): void {
        let modal = this.modalCtrl.create('SignUpPage');
        modal.onDidDismiss(success => {
            if (success) {
                // Since this is also a modal, we should dismiss this view
                this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
            }
        });
        modal.present();
    }

}
```

And...

```
@Component({
    selector: 'page-sign-up',
    templateUrl: 'sign-up.html'
})
export class SignUpPage {

    constructor(private viewCtrl: ViewController) {}

    // ...

    // Method that redirects the user to the SignUpPage
    public signUp(): void {
        //...

        // Return true if the user was able to sign up
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss(true);
    }

    public close() {
        // Close only this modal, but not the SignInPage modal
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss(false);
    }

}
```